# Cannot append to JS object in HighCharts callback, in Vue

Tags: json, highcharts, vuejs2, vue-component, vue2-highcharts

I am using Vue 3.9.3, along with [highcharts-vue 1.3.5](https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-vue#readme) . I am trying to put into an object each highchart, as it loads, so then I have access to any chart I want like

`myCharts.aChart` or

`myCharts.anotherChart`,

so I can easily do `myCharts.anotherChart.addData`

In practice I do,

`<highcharts :constructor-type="'stockChart'" :options="options" :callback="chartcallback" ></highcharts>`

and then

```
    data(){
      return{     
        charts:{}
      }
    },
  methods:{ 

       chartcallback(hc){
          let obj = {[hc.options.id] : hc};
          this.charts = Object.assign(this.charts, obj); 

          //also tried this 
          const newChart = {id:hc.options.id, chart : hc};
          this.$set(this.charts, newChart.id, newChart);

          //also tried this
           this.charts = Object.assign({}, this.charts, {
             [hc.options.id] : hc
           });

          //also tried this               
          this.charts[hc.options.id]= hc;

          console.log('test ', this.charts);
        } 
  }
```

and then I would `watch` my data and each time they change, I would add data to each highchart,

```
    watch: {
      myData: { 
        immediate: true,
        deep: true,             
        handler(){ 
            this.charts.NameChart.series[0].setData(this.myData[0], true);
            this.charts.DrinkChart.series[0].setData(this.myData[1], true);
            //etc....
```

`this.charts.NameChart` or `this.charts.DrinkChart` should be constructed in `chartcallback` and  NameChart, DrinkChart is the value of `hc.options.id` `hc.options.id` always has a value and it is there, I checked.

**The problem is**

at the end of `chartcallback` where I do `console.log('test ', this.charts);`, the produced obj is

```
//first time
{NameChart:chart}

//second time
{NameChart:chart}
```

but it should be

```
//first time
{NameChart:chart}

//second time
{NameChart:chart,
DrinkChart:chart}
```

It looks like it overwrites the `this.charts` every time `chartcallback` is called. I tried several methods, as I note, but nothing works.

What can I do ?

Thanks

Comment: Are you able to reproduce your case on the online editor which I could work on?